# Guava why toStringFunction not a generic function?

Tags: java, generics, guava

the Guava toStringFunction() has the following declaration:

```
public static Function<Object, String> toStringFunction() { ... }
```

All non-primitive roots at Object, so the function works well.

but when I try to compose  it with another function, such as:

```
Function<Integer, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap),
                                                 Functions.toStringFunction());
```

where someMap variable is a map< String, Double>, So i expect toStringFunction converts Integer to String and then forMap converts String to Double. 
But  I get a compiler error:

```
    Function<Integer, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap),
                                                    ^
  required: Function<Integer,Double>
  found:    Function<Object,Double>
2 errors
```

My two questions are:

1.how to specifically tell the compiler that toStringFunction should be Function< Integer, String>? A simple cast will not work, and I am looking for a real composition of the two functions.

```
Function< Integer, String> g1 = (Function< Integer, String>)Functions.toStringFunction(); 

// cause error
```

2.Had the toStringFunction written as the following:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
  public static <E> Function<E, String> toStringFunction(){
    return (Function<E, String>) ToStringFunction.INSTANCE;
  }

  // enum singleton pattern
  private enum ToStringFunction implements Function<Object, String>{
    INSTANCE;


    // @Override public String toString(){
    //   return "Functions.toStringFunction()";
    // }

    @Override public String apply(Object o){
      return o.toString();
    }
  }
```

I can specify the type:

```
Function<Integer, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap),
                                                 Functions.<Integer>toStringFunction());
```

and this works fine. But what is the motivation for the version Guava team have right now?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question "why" (hence posting as a comment), but: `Functions.compose` uses a wildcard in its second parameter's output-type to allow some flexibility, so although you can't write `Functions.<Integer>toStringFunction()`, you can create an Integer-to-String function by writing `Functions.compose(Functions.toStringFunction(), Functions.<Integer>identity())`. And of course, in Java 8 you can simply write `Integer::toString`. :-)

Comment: Well, if a `Map<K, V>` has its `Map.get(key)` method with `key` being of type `Object`, I don't see why the Guava team would do any different :P Now, being serious, I believe it's a bug or a decision taken long ago that has proven to be not the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After discussion in comments:**

To fix the compilation error:

```
Function<Object, Double> f1 = 
    Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap), Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Your question implies you want a `Function<Integer, Double>` instead of `Function<Object, Double>`. Based on the discussion in the comments, and trying to think of other scenarios, the only reason you will want this is for validation. The code in the toStringFunction is out of your control, so validation in that function is out of question. As far as validation in the forMap function, that code is also out of your control. If you want to protect against IllegalArgumentException, you will have to perform this validation whether the input you provide is an Object or an Integer. So that validation too is out of scope of the forMap, toStringFunction, and compose, because none of these functions provide that kind of validation and you have to write your own code to do this (either catch the exception and handle it or pre-validate in some way before calling this composed Function).

For the specific compose, you gain nothing by changing the input parameter of the Function from Object to Integer, because the Function only needs the methods present in Object, so it is a good decision as it simplifies things in this case and makes it more widely usable. Say you were able to enforce the parameter type as Integer, you still have gained absolutely no benefit whatsoever, whether it is validation for IllegalArgumentException or something else you are attempting.

When designing an API, you want it to be usable by as many consumers as possible, without having to go out of your way, i.e. you should use the highest level class that satisfies your requirements. By using Object in toStringFunction, the Guava function is satisfying this principle. This makes the function more generic and more widely usable. That is the reason for choosing Object instead of parameterizing this Function.

If the Function took a parameter, it would do nothing differently as it is doing right now, so why use a parameter when it is not required. This approach simplifies the design greatly instead of adding something that is not required.

**Original answer:**

Every class is a child of Object, and the Function is only calling toString on the input which is present in the Object class. So in this case, declaring a Function is equivalent to declaring Function. You will gain nothing by changing the input parameter of the Function from Object to Integer, because the Function only needs the methods present in Object, so it is a good decision as it simplifies things in this case.

As far as possible, you should use the highest level class that satisfies your requirements. This makes the function more generic and more widely usable. That is the reason for choosing Object instead of parameterizing this Function.

To fix the compilation error:  Function f1 = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap), Functions.toStringFunction());

Comment: after erasure, the generic becomes Object, the second version provides the chance to actually force the type, as shown in the example

Comment: but what do you achieve by specifying the type? in this case the function is fixed and it doesn't matter what type you pass it. If the type does matter then I can see a case for it, but since every type has toString there is no point in having a type

Comment: @fasttooth have you understood the answer? erasure is not even relevant in this case. there is no reason to do what you want to do

Comment: well, can you write me a compose function out of toStringFunction() and forMap<String, Double> ? using only toStringFunnction(), forMap() and compose function and any casting you like

Comment: Yes: `Function<Object, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(someMap), Functions.toStringFunction());`

Comment: In fact, the compiler is even telling you what you need to do in order to fix it

Comment: using toStringFunction limits the input type to be Object, which is something undesirable.

Comment: @fasttooth Every type is Object, how is it a limitation? If anything it's too flexible. I feel you're deviating from the question. You asked why it's done this way, the reason is to have input type be as generic as possible, and there is nothing more generic than Object

Comment: And I'm sure this is the answer to your question, whether or not you like the answer

Comment: I am open to other possible discussions, I haven't taken any action about your answer.

Comment: Well you haven't also provided a rational argument in favor of what you want to do. Integer is an Object and since the code in the function is out of your control it shouldn't matter to you what the function accepts. It's like telling a service owner to change their api because you want it to be stricter. If the service owner wants to have an open api then it is their decision as long as it doesn't impact the consumer. In this case I cannot see any way that parameterizing will help

Comment: @tinker The OP has a strong argument: A method from the same library does not compile due to this problem. That is enough for me. However, you have a good point as well, though yours is more of a theory, while OP's is 100% practical. Anyway, I don't think your answer should be downvoted.

Comment: @Magnamag The method does compile. Please read my comment. I will update the answer to reflect this. It would be practical if this were true, but it's not. And what I'm saying is not a theory, it is a best practice when implementing an api

Comment: @tinker I know it compiles if you change `Function<Integer, Double>` to `Function<Object, Double>`. I've carefully read the question, your answer and every comment. The OP wants to transform `Integer`s to `Double`s, not any object to a `Double`, because that would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the object passed wouldn't be an `Integer`.

Comment: @magnamag Yes, but that kind of validation is beyond the scope of the toStringFunction. The same argument holds for integers that wouldn't be present in the map. We are talking about the api design of toStringFunction, validation of any kind would be beyond the scope because there is no limit to what would need to be validated in more complex cases of compose on two complex functions taking custom object types

Comment: @tinker You may be right, but I find practical arguments more convincing.

Comment: @Magnamag the compose specified looks very specific and the input should always be present in the map as a string. If that's not the case then this compose itself is being used incorrectly IMO

Comment: @Magnamag please see the updated answer, I have attempted to make things more clear and explain the case for my answer, showing the ineffectiveness of what was desired.

Comment: @Magnamag No, using a `Function<Integer, Double>` would not lead to `IllegalArgumentException`s when given a wrong object (which would be possible after an unchecked cast). Instead it would silently accept the object and invoke `toString()`, so you gain nothing from the input type being restricted.

Comment: @PhilippWendler and @tinker: Agreed, now I see that declaring the function as `Function<Object, Double>` is OK. And passing an object of a type different than `Integer` might throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or not, depending on the entries contained on the map, not on the type that the function accepts. If the OP wants to narrow the type that the function accepts, then my helper method approach is what he needs. :)

Answer (score 8):

The reason `toStringFunction()` is a `Function<Object, String>` and not a `Function<T, String>` is, quite simply, because you can call `toString()` on any `Object`. It is literally a function that takes an object and returns a string. Guava avoids introducing type parameters (and wildcard generics) to methods where they serve no purpose.

The issue in your example is that you are trying to type your `f1` function as `Function<Integer, Double>` when it is in fact a `Function<Object, Double>`: it can take any object, call `toString()` on it, pass that string to your `forMap` function and get a result.

Furthermore, assuming proper use of generics, there shouldn't be any actual necessity for your function's type to be `Function<Integer, Double>` rather than `Function<Object, Double>`, since most code that accepts a function and uses it to do something should accept something like `Function<? super F, ? extends T>`. So the real question here is "why do you want to refer to a `Function<Object, Double>` as a `Function<Integer, Double>`"?

Comment: I've been driving at the same point and question for hours now but if you see the comments on my answer you'll notice it's leading to no avail, the OP doesn't see reason because they're fixated on the idea that type parameters give some magical benefits like validation, whereas in this case it makes no difference

Comment: @tinker: Yep, totally agree with what you've been saying. Just wanted to try to explain it my own way.

Comment: Always good to see an experienced user's answer. I was referring to the last line in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why Guava does not declare it as `Function<T, String>` (although it could be done) is explained by one of the Guava team members in this [comment to a similar question in their bug tracker](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1927#issuecomment-68305122):

> We decided that the purpose of type parameters and wildcards in a library API is to ensure that the method *can be called* with any parameter types that make logical sense. Once that condition is met, we stop, instead of continuing to also add type params/wildcards that serve only to let you "massage" the specific result type you want to get.

So basically they decided that it is not worth it. Instead of changing methods like `toStringFunction` to return a `Function<T, String>`, consumers of generic types should instead to be changed such that they allow to be given a `Function<? super F, ? extends T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Guava team's motivation for this behavior, I really don't know. Maybe one of them should respond that.

Regarding the compilation error, you need a helper method in order to perform the cast:

```
public class Sample {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> Function<T, String> checkedToStringFunction() {
        return (Function<T, String>) Functions.toStringFunction();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> someMap = new HashMap<>();

        Function<Integer, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(
            Functions.forMap(someMap), 
            checkedToStringFunction()); // compiles fine
    }
}
```

This way, the compiler can safely infer the parameter types.

**EDIT:**

I was told that this technique might lead to *heap pollution*. While this might be true from a theoretical point of view, in practice, I fail to see how this might lead to a `ClassCastException`, or to any other runtime error, since the helper method is `private` and only used to infer the `Function` type parameters.

If I forced the generic type, i.e:

```
Function<Integer, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(
    Functions.forMap(someMap), 
    Sample.<BigInteger> checkedToStringFunction()); // compilation error
```

I'd get a compilation error. To fix it, I'd need to change the first type parameter of the `f1` `Function` to:

```
Function<BigInteger, Double> f1 = Functions.compose(
    Functions.forMap(someMap), 
    Sample.<BigInteger> checkedToStringFunction()); // compiles fine
```

*Note:*

I know what's heap pollution:

```
private static <S, T> S convert(T arg) { 
    return (S) arg;  // unchecked warning 
} 

Number n = convert(new Long(5L)); // fine 
String s = convert(new Long(5L)); // ClassCastException
```

In this example I'm casting to the given type variable, while in the solution I'm suggesting, I'm casting to a parameterized type.

Specifficaly, I'm casting from `Function<Object, Double>` to `Function<Integer, Double>`. I see it as a *narrowing* type conversion, so I believe it's legal and safe. Please let me know if I'm OK with this and if it's worth taking the risk.

Comment: That is not "safe"; you're tricking the compiler into casting an instance of `Function<Object, String>` to type `Function<Integer, String>`. This is known as "heap pollution". (And if you're going to do it at all, it's simpler to do it by just casting to the raw type `Function`. No need for the helper-method.)

Comment: @ruakh In this case, it is indeed safe to do this cast: it will never lead to a `ClassCastException` at runtime. It would use the term "heap pollution" for cases where it is not safe, like casting a `List<Object>` to a `List<String>`.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: It will not lead to a `ClassCastException` at runtime as long as generics are implemented via erasure. It's not legal -- it's a dirty hack of the sort that belongs in C code, not Java code.

Comment: @ruakh Well, if I can do it, it's legal. It's kind of a hack, yes, but I wouldn't consider it to be a "dirty" one. Come on, we're talking about a cast that would no longer have effect on runtime, since it only affects a parameterized type. What I'm returning, is still a `Function`.

Comment: Re: "if I can do it, it's legal": This is as true in software as it is in the courts. ;-)

Comment: @ruakh Let the compiler be the judge :-P Anyways, I got your point, and it's quite a good one. Thanks for sharing your arguments.

Comment: @Magnamag: The compiler told you its judgment: it says that it can't tell whether this is correct. (And as it happens, it's *not* correct.) You then told the compiler to STFU -- which you can't do in a real court, so in that respect it's different. :-)